# SDL_TTF Scrolling console

Tags: c++, scroll, sdl, truetype

I'm currently using SDL_TTF to try and make a scrolling console, the console part works fine, but I'm having problems with the scrolling part.

I currently have a srcRect and a dstRect which I'm using to do this.

Basically, I'm creating a surface for a block of text and then cropping out a sample of the text the size of the console. Then, the crops Y-axis is changed to move further down the surface until it reaches the bottom.

I want the text to be moved back into the box whenever it leaves.

I created a simple diagram, using an image from a tutorial that can be found [here.](https://interhacker.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/chapter-5-graphics-in-sdl/)

(I also need to clarify that I am not using the image below, it's only an example. My "image" is the SDL_TTF surface that I'm using)
[image]

It should be noted, I did not actually use that tutorial, just the image.

And when we compare this concept to the code:

```
#include "Console.h"

void Console::init(int x, int y, int w, int h){
    consoleX = x;
    consoleY = y;

    consoleW = w;
    consoleH = h;

    srcRect = {0, 0, w, h};

    dstRect = {x, y, w, h};

    backRect = {x, y, w, h};

    color = {255, 255, 255};

    consoleText = "Hey";
}

void Console::promptText(std::string text, std::string buttons[]){
    consoleText += text + "\n";

}

void Console::handleEvents(){

}

void Console::render(SDL_Renderer *renderer){
    surface = TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped(ResourceManager::GetInstance().getFont("mainFont"), consoleText.c_str(), color, consoleW);
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

    while((consoleY - srcRect.y + surface->h) > (consoleH + consoleY)){
        srcRect.y += 1;
    }

    SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &backRect);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, &srcRect, &dstRect);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
}

void Console::close(){

}
```

The problem I'm having is that the text just keeps scrolling:

[image]

Like I said, I want it to only scroll if the position of the bottom of the text is below(>) the bottom of the console.

I'm interested to see if this is a problem with my concept, or code itself.

Comment: I tried to understand the question but failed. What does that picture have to do with the text? Where is the picture on the final gif? If it isn't relevant remove it. Please clarify your question so someone can answer it.

Comment: The picture was just an example of how the srcRect and dstRect work,  The text itself is the picture.

Comment: Try to output the y-position of the console with `cout`; or use the debugger to get information about it. Possibly you have a wrong formula for the handle calculation, and you just need to subtract or add the height. (Probably it stops at the bottom of text)